# What does ^ 1 mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I saw a solution to a leetcode problem:

```
var findComplement = function(num) {
    let result = ''
    const binary = num.toString(2)
    for (let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        result += binary[i] ^ 1
    }
    return parseInt(result, 2)
};
```

What does `^ 1` mean? I never saw the `^` operator before in Javascript and I can't find it in documentation.

Comment: This is operator in JavaScript. Its bitwise called XOR operator

Comment: See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the list of operators [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp), it tells you that this is the bitwise XOR operator

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments, I should've given a better explanation:

XOR stands for exclusive-or, which means that only one of the two operands (or bits) can be a 1. If you think of 1 as true and 0 as false, then if only one of the operands is true, this will result in true, otherwise this will result in false. Bitwise means that this operation is applied individually to each bit, and that each bit will be replaced by the result of the operation. So in this case, each bit of `binary[i]` will be replaced by the value of that bit XORed with 1. Since 1 is supplied as the second operand, this will change all the 0s to 1s and all the 1s to 0s, based on the rules of a XOR operation. This is why XOR can be used as a "not equals" operation

Comment: When answering, try to not merely link to an offsite resource (particularly not w3schools which is frequently incorrect or outdated). The preferred practice of Stack Overflow is to have self contained questions and answers. Telling someone it is the bitwise XOR operator does not really give them a lot of information if they don't already understand what that is, which is likely since they are asking about it. It is better to explain what it is and how it is actually used, and then maybe include and offsite resource for further reading after that if the concept is complex enough to warrant it.

Answer (score 1):

it is the bitwise XOR operator.
Returns a 1 in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either but not both operands are 1s.
Example

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 0 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```